# Type safe keys with Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my perfect idea of day: Strong typed ids in Entity Framework.

Motivation:

1. Comparing ModelTypeA.ID and ModelTypeB.ID is (at least almost) always an error. Why not compiletime handle it?
2. If you are using example per request DbContext its easy to implement get directly model from id. "id.Value.ProductNumber"
3. Code will be more self declarative.
4. They are just naturally typed so why not?

Ok here is my implementation. I hope its pretty self declarative what I mean.

```
//Optional interface may be handy on some scenarios
public interface Identifiable<T> where T : class, Identifiable<T>
{
    DbId<T> ID { get; set; }
}

public class TestModel1 : Identifiable<TestModel1>
{
    [Key]
    public DbId<TestModel1> ID { get; set; }
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
}

public class TestModel2 : Identifiable<TestModel2>
{
    [Key]
    public DbId<TestModel2> ID { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public DbId<TestModel1> TestModel1ID { get; set; }
    public virtual TestModel1 TestModel1 { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class DbId<T> where T : class
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator DbId<T>(int id)
    {
        var c = new DbId<T>() { ID = id };
        return c;
    }

    public static implicit operator int (DbId<T> id)
    {
        return id.ID;
    }       
}
```

When creating migration its jus complain that there is no key. When trying to set key on fluent api it give more precious error: The property 'ID' cannot be used as a key property on the entity 'MyNs.Models.TestModel1' because the property type is not a valid key type. Only scalar types, string and byte[] are supported key types.

Ok understood key cannot be any type but data of my type is just one int witch even has implicit conversions. Inheriting int in this situation is very tempting but like we know its impossible.

Primary question: How to finish this and tell to EF that converting my DbId to int and back is not rocket science.

Secondary question: Is this good idea? Why? Do you suggest feature request if this is not currently possible?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but that is an awful amount of work to try to prevent something that would very rarely happen on accident. I'd rely on testing one level of abstraction higher instead of doing this.

Comment: Why this is awful amount of work? After implemented once (and base solution is there already) solution is portable/shareable and only difrence is to replace "int" with "DbId<SomeModel>" when writing new code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand your goal: your aim is to encapsulate the primary key of each model such that primary keys of two different models cannot be compared directly. So, for example, you would want to avoid the comparison `Customer.ID == Order.ID` at compile time.

However, in your code example, the `implicit operator` for `int <-> DbId<T>` works against your goal because this code [compiles](http://csharppad.com/gist/eef2c92d4e2c3228afa8):

```
var model1 = new TestModel1() {ID = 1};
var model2 = new TestModel2() {ID = 2};
Console.WriteLine(model1.ID == model2.ID);
```

So, if I follow your reasoning, it would not work even if EF6+ allowed `[Key]` on a class (other than `string`.)

Getting back to basics, if you believe the name `ID` is too ambiguous, why not follow the Entity Framework [Primary Key Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962) of *class name followed by "ID"*?

Example:

```
public class Customer
{
    // [Key] is implicit by convention
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    // [Key] is implicit by convention
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }
    // [ForeignKey("Customer")] is implicit by convention
    public int CustomerID{ get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

This naming convention (along with plain `ID`) is the convention I see the most in Entity Framework code. So, it has the major benefit of allowing other people to step in and seamlessly acclimate and maintain your code (a benefit that we tinkerers are all guilty of overlooking sometimes!)

Looking at your motivations...

> Comparing ModelTypeA.ID and ModelTypeB.ID is (at least almost) always an error.

Are you solving a problem that isn't actually a problem? How often do programmers really screw up `Order.CustomerID == Customer.CustomerID`?

> Code will be more self declarative.

Up to debate? If I spot `DbId<Customer> id = Customer.ID` in someone's code, is it really more declarative than `int id = Customer.CustomerID`?

That said, I applaud your effort! Solving problems is what we programmers love to do. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes those implicit operators were only desperate try to get it work at least somehow with EF.

In big picture our current EF usage is messed up and I am trying to rethink this orm-query area. In the product we are actually using same naming convention you mentioned but I am planning to do some interface rich generic (etc) helper stuff to query managment. It require more abstraction so diffrent ID name per type dosen't fit well to my Identifiable interface. But work in progress...

Comment: "How often do programmers really screw up Order.CustomerID == Customer.CustomerID?" - You are right, not so many times. There is not huge problem with current usage style. But if we upgrade these dummy identifier numbers for something more smarter I believe we can develop better solutions on top of that. Just like memory addresses are just numbers but nowdays references can handle memory automaticly and  we don't threat them eather as numbers on language level.

Comment: `How often do programmers really screw up Order.CustomerID == Customer.CustomerID` - it is more likely that they screw up like this: `ProductRepository.ById(order.PersonId);` (auto-complete error, because `PersonId` was top of the list when I typed `.P`) - leading to very difficult to diagnose bugs. If the `ById` method only accepted `ProductId`, this wouldn't happen. In risk terms, it is not highly likely to happen, but it can be highly costly when it eventually does. When assessing risk, you need to look beyond frequency as that is too simplistic a view.